# how is CSS scroll-snap specified, and it isn't working on firefox

Tags: html, css, haskell-snap-framework

I want to make some scroll snapping on each section.
According to the docs, the container should have scroll-snap-type enabled,

and the direct child will be snapped to.

with the following code, how come it doesn't work. However, if i place  on body {scroll-snap-type: y mandatory} it works..except only on chrome and safari.. firefox nightly seem to have problems.

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
}

div {

    scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
}

section {
    scroll-snap-align: start;
    height: 100vh;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <section></section>
        <section></section>
        <section></section>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

You need update css as per below snippet more guideline are available on [developer.mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-snap-type).

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

div {
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
  overflow: auto;
  outline: 1px dashed lightgray;
  flex: none;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  height: 100vh;
}

section {
  scroll-snap-align: start;
  height: 100vh;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: green;
  flex: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <section></section>
  <section></section>
  <section></section>
</div>
```

Comment: I just ran this code snippet on Firefox and it's not working either.